# UPDATE Column value with a count of rows with certain values

Tags: sql-server, join, count, sql-update

Have to update column value with a count of player's rows in table.

Table_Player :

```
ID  | PlayerNr  | session_type  | Date          | CountSes | 
------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1001      | cancelled     | 2017-01-01    |
2   | 1001      | ready         | 2017-06-06    | 
3   | 1002      | ready         | 2017-02-02    |
4   | 1002      | ready         | 2017-04-04    |
5   | 1003      | waiting       | 2017-03-03    | 
6   | 1003      | ready         | 2017-05-05    | 
7   | 1004      | waiting       | 2017-10-10    | 
8   | 1004      | ready         | 2017-11-11    | 
9   | 1004      | waiting       | 2017-12-12    | 
10  | 0         | test          |               |
```

I've used :

```
UPDATE a
SET a.CountSes = b.cnt
FROM Table_Player a 
JOIN
 (SELECT PlayerNr, COUNT(*) cnt 
    FROM Table_Player
    WHERE PlayerNr <> '0'
  GROUP BY PlayerNr) 
b ON a.PlayerNr = b.PlayerNr
```

This does the job but now I need a more detailed count.

Rules are:

1. session_type = 'waiting' . . Row will be counted only when it's the newest row of player.
2. PlayerNr = '0' . . . . . . . . . . . Dummy-player's rows will be ignored.

From sample above, the result should be:

```
ID  | PlayerNr  | session_type  | Date          | CountSes | 
------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1001      | cancelled     | 2017-01-01    |   2
2   | 1001      | ready         | 2017-06-06    |   2 
3   | 1002      | ready         | 2017-02-02    |   2
4   | 1002      | ready         | 2017-04-04    |   2
5   | 1003      | waiting       | 2017-03-03    |   1 
6   | 1003      | ready         | 2017-05-05    |   1 
7   | 1004      | waiting       | 2017-10-10    |   2 
8   | 1004      | ready         | 2017-11-11    |   2 
9   | 1004      | waiting       | 2017-12-12    |   2 
10  | 0         | test          |               |
```

This goes beyond my knowledge, any Hints ? 
Database is SQL Server 2014 SP2.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share the table schema with sample data?

Comment: SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Player](
 [ID] [int] NULL,
 [PlayerNr] [int] NULL,
 [session_type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [DateSession] [date] NULL,
 [CountSes] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: ID PlayerNr session_type DateSession CountSes
1 1001 cancelled 2017-01-01 0
2 1001 ready     2017-06-06 0
3 1002 ready     2017-02-02 0
4 1002 ready     2017-04-04 0
5 1003 waiting   2017-03-03 0
6 1003 ready     2017-05-05 0
7 1004 waiting   2017-10-10 0
8 1004 ready     2017-11-11 0
9 1004 waiting   2017-12-12 0
10 0 test 1900-01-01 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `IIF` and Partitioning function `ROW_NUMBER` to filter ignore waiting rows that are not new and also used `SUM` instead of `COUNT`

```
UPDATE t
SET CountSes = ISNULL(CNT, 0)
FROM Table_Player as t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(IIF(session_type = 'waiting'
                AND RN > 1, 0, 1)) AS CNT
        , PlayerNr
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY PlayerNr ORDER BY DATE DESC
                ) RN
        FROM Table_Player
        WHERE (PlayerNr <> 0)
        ) t
    GROUP BY PlayerNr
    ) as p ON p.PlayerNr = t.PlayerNr
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NBHXYL39648

Comment: Works perfectly